# Change errorbar size

Tags: matplotlib

I have to change the size of the markers in my plot (making them bigger). How is it possible to change the width of errorbars too? I'm using `matplotlib`. Thanks.

```
plot=ax.errorbar(x,y, yerr=[y1,y2], color='red', fmt='.', markersize='10', ecolor='red',capsize=4)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can make the error bar thicker by setting the `elinewidth` attribute in the call to errorbar(x,y,...) [errorbar documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=errorbar#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar).  But the length of the error bar is your data: you can't change the length without changing the error that it represents.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define x,y, y1,y2 here ...

plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(x,y, yerr=[y1,y2], color='red', fmt='.', markersize='10', ecolor='red',capsize=4, elinewidth=2)
```

Comment: Thanks Bonlenfum. I know that the length depends on my data, but is there any possibility to enlarge both the points and the error bars?

Comment: @ely i know you asked this years ago, but i see that bonlenfum didn't really answer your question.  `markersize` sets the sizes of the markers (what you call the "points," i believe) and `elinewidth` sets the width of the errorbars.

Comment: If using `plt.bar()` or other types which can indirectly draw error bars, one can use: `error_kw={'elinewidth': 2}`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the *linewidth* of the cap of the errorbar to say 2, then use the following:

```
(_, caps, _) = errorbar(x, y, yerr=[y1,y2], elinewidth=2)
for cap in caps:
     cap.set_markeredgewidth(2)
```

Comment: so `capsize` sets the length of the caps, and `set_markeredgewidth` sets the width.